# Make ADAM upload to specified folder

Tags: 2sxc

I want to let my content admins use the drag and drop upload through ADAM but keep the images they upload in a specified folder. For example, I have a field called "Background" which is a hyperlink. I've set it to use the Image Manager, and specified the folder to be /Images/landing-backgrounds. But when they drag and drop through ADAM, it puts the .jpg in an ADAM folder. The problem is that they can't access this image later on through /Images/landing-backgrounds. Is there a way I can force them to upload to the specified folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment this is not configurable. The reason is that the concept/idea in ADAM is "automatic digital asset management" - and a core part of the automatic is related to "belongs to the item 7503, and only to item 7503".

The moment you want to re-use the assets in other scenarios / items, it's not "automatic management" any more, but simply a nicer upload / file-picker than DNN provides.

So this is currently not possible with ADAM, for this you need to use the "dnn standard" telerik-file-upload component